# Recuperar último valor digitado em uma coluna específica do Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Preciso recuperar o último valor digitado em uma célula específica da planilha, por exemplo:

---

```
coluna ID
1
2
3
4
...
2550
```

---

Preciso pegar o valor do `ID (2550)` para poder incrementar e executar outras ações.

Tentei usando `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row`, porém ele me retorna o número da linha da planilha, mas o que eu preciso é o valor do campo.

Alguém consegue me ajudar com este problema?

Comment: Tens de usar a propriedade `value`: `Range("A1").End(xlDown).Value`